# How to get into IT industry/consulting work without forfeiting the academic duties

Tags: job-search, consulting

I am currently a tenure-track Assistant Professor of Computer Science/Information Technology. I like the academic job that I have been doing over last five years and I am comfortable with the teaching and research requirements. I will be going for the tenure this upcoming Fall. I also have prior extensive experience working in IT services industry, working over 15 years.

I am itching to get into IT industry/IT consulting full time during the Summer break and if possible  may be part time (10 to 20 hours per week) during regular semester practicing the concepts I teach / research. I am hoping to accomplish the IT work remotely with minimal travel. Maybe I can relocate just in the Summer (if needed).

Issue is though I have 15+ years IT industry experience, I have not worked in the IT industry for last 5+ years, though I have been teaching and researching on the skills that are very hot in the IT industry. I am not sure how to articulate my abilities to the potential client/employer, successfully clear the interview process and get the gig.

Please advise if this is possible and how to approach this, if you or someone you know are already successful in this aspect.

Comment: Your university likely has a policy on consulting.  My guess is they won't allow 10-20 hours per week during the semester.  Maybe 8.

Comment: The part about "how to get hired" might be better on Workplace.SE.  By the nature of this site, it isn't particularly populated by people with great insight into industry employment.

Comment: Could you start with some informal networking?  That might give you the self-confidence and buzz phrases you'll need.  (It sounds to me like that's all that's missing....)